# Bitcoin Core Unbuntu Custom Data Directory Does not Navigate to Secondary Internal Hard Drive

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, storage, datadir

I have a laptop computer with 2 solid state internal 1000 GB hard drives. I have the operating system installed on drive 1 and I have the secondary drive formatted (ext4 file system), partitioned and mounted to /media/valdy/Bitcoin.

I can navigate to that location via the terminal and via files GUI.

I have installed bitcoin core via Unbuntu Software GUI.

I run bitcoin core GUI and select the option to "use a custom data directory". I try to navigate to /media/valdy/Bitcoin and i can't. It does not see the user folder "valdy" inside the media folder. I can type the path in and it gives me the correct available disk space for the drive. But when i hit enter i get the following error "Error: Specified data directory "/media/valdy/Bitcoin/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin" cannot be created.

Please advise how i can go about putting the data directory on a separate hard rive that i want to dedicate to all things bitcoin-core.

Comment: Have you checked permissions of all elements of the path? What is the EUID of the Bitcoin-qt process?